# Problem with MySQL query update and SQLite

Tags: javascript, mysql

My table is:

```
id |    les_mo_id      |    les_comp     |    les_ch_comp
.1.|...................|........0....... |...................
.2.|........1..........|.................|.........1.........
.3.|........1..........|.................|.........1.........
.4.|...................|........0....... |...................
.5.|........4..........|.................|.........2.........
.6.|........4..........|.................|.........1.........
.7.|...................|........0........|...................
.8.|........7..........|.................|.........1.........
.9.|........7..........|.................|.........4.........
```

I have to run the query, but I don't know how to set it. I'm just learning this language.

I need to update the columns 'les_comp' adding all the values of the columns 'les_ch_comp' having with id les_mo_id = 1

This is my query

```
UPDATE base_app SET les_comp = (SELECT SUM(les_ch_comp) WHERE les_mo_id = "1") WHERE id = "1";
```

Comment: Your subquery has no `FROM`.

Comment: Don't you need a les_ch_comp is null in your update where clause too?   At the very end

Answer (score 0):

Just like UUeerdo sugests:

UPDATE base_app
SET les_comp = (SELECT SUM(les_ch_comp) **FROM base_app** WHERE les_mo_id = "1") WHERE id = "1"

Answer (score 0):

There should be FROM in your query. Try:

```
UPDATE base_app SET lesson_complete = (SELECT SUM(lesson_child_complete) FROM 
base_app WHERE lesson_mother_id = "1") WHERE id = "1"
```

Comment: #1093 - Table 'base_app' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data